# numerotate rows with the same ID

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(table1.eventTime, '%Y %D %M') AS DAY, table1.ID, table1.eventTime, COUNT(*)
FROM table1 table1
GROUP BY from_unixtime(table1.eventTime, '%Y %D %M'), table1.ID, table1.eventTime
```

This is giving me the following output:

```
 DAY                    ID      eventTime COUNT(*)  
2017 10th November      815     1510275600  1  
2017 10th November      902     1510275600  1  
2017 10th November      1202    1510275600  1  
2017 10th November      1202    1510279200  1  
2017 10th November      1202    1510282800  1  
2017 10th November      1202    1510286400  1  
2017 10th November      1342    1510275600  1  
2017 10th November      1404    1510275600  1  
2017 10th November      1404    1510275600  1
```

How can i achieve this?

```
 DAY                 ID      eventTime COUNT(*)  
2017 10th November  815     1510275600  1  
2017 10th November  902     1510275600  1  
2017 10th November  1202    1510275600  1  
2017 10th November  1202    1510279200  2  
2017 10th November  1202    1510282800  3  
2017 10th November  1202    1510286400  4  
2017 10th November  1342    1510275600  1  
2017 10th November  1404    1510275600  1  
2017 10th November  1404    1510275600  2
```

In fact what i need is to group by day and based on the eventTime to make a numbering where the ID is same.

Comment: I see the counts are changed, but to know why it was changed I need to see some sample data. So Can you provide some sample data ?

Comment: if you add 4 spaces at the start of lines of code then they are formatted correctly.. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @Toro Sandor Your edit acutally makes this less readable , what did you change and can you format it please.

Comment: You seem to want to row number based on id so I'm a bit confused by your group by.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically after mysql row number simulation. There are loads of examples in SO and here's another

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(Dt date, ID  int ,eventtime int);
insert into t values
('2017-11-10' ,815  ,1510275600), 
('2017-11-10' ,902  ,1510275600),
('2017-11-10' ,1202 ,1510275600),
('2017-11-10' ,1202 ,1510279200),
('2017-11-10' ,1202 ,1510282800),
('2017-11-10' ,1202 ,1510286400),
('2017-11-10' ,1342 ,1510275600),
('2017-11-10' ,1404 ,1510275600),
('2017-11-10' ,1404 ,1510275600);

select dt,id,eventtime,
         if(id <> @p,@rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rownumber,
         @p:=id p
from t , (select @rn:=0,@p:=0) r
order  by id,dt,eventtime
```

result

```
+------------+------+------------+-----------+------+
| dt         | id   | eventtime  | rownumber | p    |
+------------+------+------------+-----------+------+
| 2017-11-10 |  815 | 1510275600 |         1 |  815 |
| 2017-11-10 |  902 | 1510275600 |         1 |  902 |
| 2017-11-10 | 1202 | 1510275600 |         1 | 1202 |
| 2017-11-10 | 1202 | 1510279200 |         2 | 1202 |
| 2017-11-10 | 1202 | 1510282800 |         3 | 1202 |
| 2017-11-10 | 1202 | 1510286400 |         4 | 1202 |
| 2017-11-10 | 1342 | 1510275600 |         1 | 1342 |
| 2017-11-10 | 1404 | 1510275600 |         1 | 1404 |
| 2017-11-10 | 1404 | 1510275600 |         2 | 1404 |
+------------+------+------------+-----------+------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```